# Python: How do I make n new lists from n inputs?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and programming in general and so I'm just trying to learn some basics.

Basically, right now I'm having a user input n amount of integers, say 2, 3, and 12. These numbers are put into a list called "numbers". From that list, I want to have each number make a new list of all the natural numbers up to and including that number.

For example:

```
inputs = 2, 4, n
numbers = [2, 4, 10]
list 1 = [1, 2]
list 2 = [1, 2, 3, 4,]
list 3 = [1, 2, ..., n-1, n]
```

My initial thoughts were to do a for loop on numbers, but how to actually make n amount of lists is eluding me.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `[list(range(1, n + 1)) for n in numbers]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pythons `range()` function is a good use for this.

You will have to make a list of list, where you can index the list as:

```
list1 = list_of_list[0]
list2 = list_of_list[1]
list3 = list_of_list[2]
```

if you get an input of numbers in a list as you mentioned

```
>>>numbers = [2, 4, 10]
>>>list_of_list = [list(range(1, n+1)) for n in numbers]
```

The output would look like this:

```
>>>list_of_list
>>>[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

This is called a list comprehension in python. You are iterating over the list numbers, and for each number, calling range and casting it as a list.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! This was a lot simpler of a solution than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get variables "list1", "list2", and "list3" dynamically in a loop. What you want to do is make a variable with nested lists.

```
numbers = [2, 4, 6]

lists = [] // Initialize it as an empty list
```

Here each iteration appends a list with the sequence from 1 to n+1 so you get the desired [1, 2] with the first input.

```
for n in numbers: 
    lists.append(range(1, n+1))
```

Afterwards you can always take each list out and put it in it's own variable, but having to add a "listx" every time you change the input isn't ideal.